# EF copying entities with Navigation properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a requirement to copy objects along with its navigation properties and create new objects. Following is what I did:

```
            // get parent location's work availability template
            WorkAvailTemplate workAvailTemplate = locationsFromDb.Where(l => l.Location2 == null).SingleOrDefault().WorkAvailTemplates.First();


            foreach (var loc in locationsToAddOrUpdate)
            {
                // add op-hours template only for the new locations (the ID sometimes can be -1
                if (loc.LocationId < 1)
                {

                    if (workAvailTemplate != null)
                    {
                        WorkAvailTemplate wt = new WorkAvailTemplate
                        {
                            Location = loc,
                            CreatedBy = this.CurrentUser.Id,
                            CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                            NumberOfRotations = workAvailTemplate.NumberOfRotations,
                            ActiveStatus = workAvailTemplate.ActiveStatus
                        };

                        ClientContext.WorkAvailTemplates.Add(wt);

                        var workAvailTemplateDays = workAvailTemplate.WorkAvailTemplateDays.ToList();

                        foreach (WorkAvailTemplateDay d in workAvailTemplateDays) 
                        {
                            WorkAvailTemplateDay wd = new WorkAvailTemplateDay
                            {
                                WorkAvailTemplate = wt,
                                WeekNumber = d.WeekNumber,
                                DayNumber = d.DayNumber,
                                ChangedBy = this.CurrentUser.Id,
                                ChangedDate = DateTime.Now
                            };
                            ClientContext.WorkAvailTemplateDays.Add(wd);

                            foreach (var r in d.WorkAvailTemplateTimeRanges)
                            {
                                WorkAvailTemplateTimeRange wr = new WorkAvailTemplateTimeRange
                                {
                                    WorkAvailTemplateDay = wd,
                                    StartTime = r.StartTime,
                                    EndTime = r.EndTime,
                                    ChangedBy = this.CurrentUser.Id,
                                    ChangedDate = DateTime.Now
                                };
                                ClientContext.WorkAvailTemplateTimeRanges.Add(wr);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I'm sure there's a better way to do this rather than creating new objects. Any thoughts?

Earlier, when I did this for a single Location object creation, i did as follow and it works fine.

```
 WorkAvailTemplate workAvailTemplate = (from wat in ClientContext.WorkAvailTemplates
                                               where wat.FkLocationId == newLocation.FkParentLocationId
                                               select wat).SingleOrDefault();

        if (workAvailTemplate != null)
        {
            workAvailTemplate.Location = newLocation;
            ClientContext.WorkAvailTemplates.Add(workAvailTemplate);

            var workAvailTemplateDays = from watd in ClientContext.WorkAvailTemplateDays
                                        join wat in ClientContext.WorkAvailTemplates on watd.FkWorkAvailTemplateId equals wat.WorkAvailTemplateId
                                        where wat.FkLocationId == newLocation.FkParentLocationId
                                        select watd;

            foreach (WorkAvailTemplateDay d in workAvailTemplateDays)
            {
                d.WorkAvailTemplate = workAvailTemplate;
                var workAvailTimeRangePerDay = (from r in ClientContext.WorkAvailTemplateTimeRanges.AsEnumerable()
                                                where r.FkWorkAvailTemplateDayId == d.WorkAvailTemplateDayId
                                                select this.f(r, d, newLocation));
                ClientContext.WorkAvailTemplateDays.Add(d);
                ClientContext.WorkAvailTemplateTimeRanges.AddRange(workAvailTimeRangePerDay);
            }
        }
```

But when I did the same for mutiple objects in a loop, it only creates for the first Location object. I don't get any errors, but simply they don't get created for others.

Comment: When I had to do copying with EF, I simply detached the entity, reset all the keys and add it back to the context. EF will generate new keys and you dont have to manually copy all the values.

Comment: When you detach an entity, wouldn't it impact the original entity? Also, I was looking for a way to avoid the double for-loop and perhaps do it using a function.

Comment: When you detach an entity, the C object is no longer linked to the database and you can do whatever you want without it having impact on the entity in the database. Only when you attach it back, it will create the link to the database again through the keys. Since you reset those before, it will see the object as a completely new entity. Gonna dig out the code that did back then.

Comment: The method I wrote back then was specific to my entities, but it hopefully shows what I meant. https://gist.github.com/Mats391/f57436ab2ae6ad91904b84d242b3191e You can also make this more generic using reflection etc. This still copies in memory, so you have to load everything from DB first

Comment: Are the LoadReference and LoadCollection methods part of DBContext? I don't see those in my intellicense list.

Comment: Ah no, sorry. Those are just wrapper methods that look like this: `public void LoadReference<T, TProperty>(T entity, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> toLoad) where T : class where TProperty : class { Entry( entity ).Reference( toLoad ).Load(); }`

Comment: Thanks. I will try that.